# Create alias with paramater in the middle

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I want to create an alias for grep like this:

```
grep argX ~/myfile
```

where argX is a parameter and myfile is always the same. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alias don't supports parameter but you can write a small script and name it i.e. "filegrep"

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "$1" /home/youruser/myfile
```

Copy the script to `/usr/bin` and you can run it with `filegrep argX` in the console.

Answer (score 13):

Aliases do not support positional parameters so you need to create a function (which you can put in `~/.bashrc`). If you really want and alias, you could alias that function.

```
function grepMe(){
    grep "$1" ~/myfile
}
```

Then, if for some reason you want there to be an alias, you can make one for the function:

```
alias grepAlias="grepMe"
```

Comment: +1. Functions are the more generalized aliases suitable for this. And just to make the message clear: you don't have to create an alias; the function name will work fine in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27882274/4970442) I found an alternative without using functions:

```
alias grepAlias='bash -xc '\''grep $0 ~/myfile'\'''
```

For example using [Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher):

```
alias superlocate='bash -xc '\''ag -g $0 --hidden'\'' 2>/dev/null'
```