# Adding one variable into multiple parts of an alias? alias nd='mkdir $1' works but cannot add anything after, why?

Tags: command-line, bash, find, alias

I have the alias

```
alias moveit='mkdir $1 && find -name "*$1*" -type f -exec mv -t ~/$1 {} +'
```

But I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to make an alias where typing `moveit pdf`

1. Creates a directory called `pdf` in the current working directory.
2. Searches for all the files that contain `pdf` in the name within the working directory and all of its subdirectories.
3. Moves those found files into the new folder called `pdf`.

I know that `pdf` will return other files that aren't `pdf`s. I'm essentially trying to create an automatic sorting script.

**I have files called:**

```
greatfile[pdf].rar
greatfile[txt].rar
greatfile[rtf].zip
badfile[pdf].zip
badfile[txt].zip
badfile[rtf].rar
okayfile[pdf].tar.bz
okayfile[txt].zip
okayfile[rtf].rar
```

And I want to sort these files into folders named `pdf`, `txt` and `rtf`, all in one script, or at least one at a time for now.

Comment: Use a shell function instead: see [Aliases - able to pass arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218630/aliases-able-to-pass-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you have to use a temporary function:

```
alias moveit='f() { mkdir "$1" && find -name "*$1*" -type f -exec mv -t "$1" {} +; unset -f f; }; f'
```

It works as expected. For example `moveit pdf` moves all files that contain the string `pdf` to a newly created directory `pdf`.

The definition part `f() { mkdir "$1" && find -name "*$1*" -type f -exec mv -t "$1" {} +; unset -f f; };` defines the function and the last part `f` calls this function.
The last part of the function definition `unset -f f;`

> removes the function definition as the alias is executed so it doesn't hang around afterwards.

For further information, have a look at this ["How to pass parameters to an alias?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias) question.

Comment: Although this will work, it's hard to imagine a real reason to do it. A function [can simply be used instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/626463/22949) of an alias. [If for some reason](https://askubuntu.com/a/301003/22949) one still needs or wants an alias, one can just make an alias to that function (though even that is rarely if ever necessary).

Comment: Thankyou zx485! Great answer!

I will have to learn how to do functions obviously, 
so thank you for pointing me in the right direction Eliah Kagan.

Comment: A situation that this would be useful is that if I were using someone else's computer only for a short time, it would be convenient to be able to just add my own .bash_aliases file with all the commands I need, without having to add any scripts to their computer. Probably not a very common situation, but it's nice to know how to do it.

Comment: You could also add all of your packages with an alias, and remove all of your packages with an alias. If I had to reinstall ubuntu, I could just add my .bash_aliases file and away I go. No other files needed.

Comment: @serge You can do all this with functions just as easily (and, in this case, much, *much* more easily). Functions can even be defined directly in `.bash_aliases`, if you want. It would be confusing to put a function definition in there, but still less confusing than putting an alias in there that is really just a wrapper for a function, where no alias is needed. Functions are most often defined in `.bashrc` or some file sourced by `.bashrc`. (`.bash_aliases` is sourced in `.bashrc`; you can source other files in it, too.)